# checking internet state from asynctask on android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-context

I have two classes; the first is an `asynctask` and the other is an `ConnectionDetector` class
which contains the code shown [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/) (3rd step),

```
public class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{


private Context context;

ConnectionDetector connectiondetector = new ConnectionDetector(context);


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    //CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION 
if(connectiondetector.isConnectingToInternet()){ //method from connectiondetector.java

            //do something 
    }
}
```

when I run this code I get a null pointer exception at the `if` statement.
is it because of the context, how do I fix this?

the `asynctask` class is called from a different activity ( `partosrecord.class` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass context to the constructor of oyur asynctask from your activity class

```
   new myTask(ActivityName.this).execute(params);
```

In your asynctask

```
    public class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
       ConnectionDetector connectiondetector
       Context mcontext;
       public myTask(Context context)
         {
            mcontext= context;
            connectiondetector = new ConnectionDetector(mcontext);
         }

       @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        if(connectiondetector.isConnectingToInternet()){
          //dosomething  
         } 
     }
```

Comment: I am calling the task like this, new myTask(activityname.this).execute(string1,string2,string3); I get the constructur is undefined lint error

Comment: you need to define the constructor in your asynctask. Have you done that?private myTask(Context context){....}

Comment: yes no errors in the asynctask class, but my activity.class shows errors at the line I told u

Comment: @user1910290 make your constructor public and try

Comment: @user1910290 you got that error because your constructor was private. Make it public and it should work.

Comment: different question but related, how do I change activities from asynctask doinbackground(), code:    firstactivity.startActivity(new Intent(mcontext, secondactivity.class));, I tried and got a null pointer exception

Comment: doinBackground() runs on the background thread. so don't update ui here. in onPostExecute() use activity context to start another activity. context.startActivity(new Intent(...));

Answer (score 0):

**Code where u call asynctask:-**

```
myTask site = new myTask(this);
site.execute();
```

or use this below code on **AsyncTask**

```
public class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{


private Context context;
ConnectionDetector connectiondetector
public myTask(Context con)
{
     context=con;
     connectiondetector = new ConnectionDetector(context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    //CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION 
if(connectiondetector.isConnectingToInternet()){ //method from connectiondetector.java

            //do something }
}
```

Comment: constructor will not have a return type. Remove void